# How to use store.subscribe in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React-redux and here I wrote a demo :
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-sijodas)
and my problem is I need to do something like to refresh page after I received the state change. but I don't know how to subscribe to the store's state change.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've edited your given demo link with a basic [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-sijodas-iuqdv8?file=component2.js).

With React Hooks and Redux you have to use `useSelector` to get your reducer's state value and `useDispatch` to modify desired reducer value. `useSelector` hook will "subscribe" to Redux changes.

I strongly recommend you to read the official [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

Comment: thank you, but still, I want to know when the state is changed. because I need to do some further action after the state changed. so I think I need store.subscribe() method. can you show me where to add this function and how to use it ?

Comment: You just need `useSelector` method, what's your need ? You want to perform an action when `refresh` value is changed in redux ?

Comment: I've edited my demo link to fullfill your needs. I've added `useEffect` hook from React to be reactive on `refresh` value change.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it's a good idea to put the refresh logic in useEffect() function. so we no longer need store.subscribe() when use redux in react . right? if we need perform further actions after the state changes, just put them in useEffect(). am I right?

Comment: You right, I've never used `store.subscribe()` method in more than two years of React development. I believe `store.subscribe()` is used under the hood by `useSelector` hook